# Using solver as part of formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a question which has been annoying me for quite some time. I have a time-series along a column, which I have to (via a formula) retrieve from another sheet, unless there is no observation or "NA" in the other sheet. The data I gather are historical quarterly growth rates in revenue.

So far, no problem. I then need to make sure quarter-on-quarter forecasts (which all should be equal within a given year) equal some pre-specified forecasted annual growth rate.

My initial thought was to calculated a difference between the rate implied by the quarter-on-quarter forecasts and the pre-specified annual growth rate and then use "Solver" to minimize it. However, this gives some problem since the last observation of the historical data obviously is dynamic, depending on what quarter is the last reported one. So it is not as easy as letting all the quarters equal the first quarter cell and then calculating the implied quarter-on-quarter growth rate from the pre-specified annual rate, because if you are in the middle of a year, you will need to take into account that you have data for, say, the first two quarters, and they are not gonna be the same as the remaining two forecasts.

Best,

UD

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reword for clarity. But based on my interpretation of what is written you have a table of values:  1) filtered for a given year, 2) all values are equal and 3) add up to a number.

Assuming you can use a separate table to do this checking then make a year column and a pre-specified column, quarterly, and annual.

The year is a year number.
The pre-specified column is your pre-specified annual rate.
The quarterly would test all numbers in a given year are equal. Use a formula like: =MAXIFS(...)=MINIFS(...) This gives true if all of the rates in a given year are equal and false if at least one rate is different.
The annual test the sum. Formula like =SUMIFS(...)=pre-specified column

I'm leaving you to fill in the ...

Comment: I have tried to make it a little bit more clearer. I appreciate it was tough to understand given the wording before!

Comment: If the below is the general form of the calculation you are looking for then I can give you pointers as far as formulas for each variable, otherwise please provide a generalized formula...                       estimated quarterly rate = (predicted annualized rate - ytd quarterly observed rates) / (4 - number of observations)